# Change the name of a video recorded with CameraCaptureUI [C++]

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, cameracapturetask

I am using C++ and XAML to develop an UI application. There is a point in the execution that I use a CameraCaptureUI to record a video. The code looks like this:

```
    CameraCaptureUI^ dialog = ref new CameraCaptureUI();
    dialog->VideoSettings->Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat::Mp4;




    concurrency::task<StorageFile^>(dialog->CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode::Video)).then([this](StorageFile^ file) {
        if (file != nullptr) {

            concurrency::task<Streams::IRandomAccessStream^>(file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read)).then([this](Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ stream) {
                //  CapturedVideo->SetSource(stream, "video/mp4");
                logger->Text = "grabando";
            });

            Windows::Foundation::Collections::IPropertySet^ appSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values;

            appSettings->Insert("CaptureVideo", PropertyValue::CreateString(file->Path));

     });
```

This is all I do to it, once I record a video, it always has "CCapture(X)" as a name, being X a away to create unique names. I tried copying the file by using CopyAsync function:

```
create_task(StorageLibrary::GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId::Videos))
                .then([this](StorageLibrary^ videosLibrary)
            {
                Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ _videoLib = videosLibrary->SaveFolder;
                if (_videoLib == nullptr)
                {
                    // In this case fall back to the local app storage since the Pictures Library is not available
                    _videoLib = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
                }


            });

            //EtiquetaVid is a string created earlier
            file->CopyAsync(_videoLib, stringToPlatformString(etiquetaVid), NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName);
```

But I nothing appeared on my video library and there were no errors to guide me.

My question is: How can I control the name of the output video? I've searched through the documentation and forums but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation I found [StorageFile.RenameAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.renameasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_RenameAsync_System_String_). As I already had a StorageFile, I could easily change the name calling this function.